# C Programming factorial outputting wrong values

Tags: c, factorial

```
int main (void)
{
   int i;
   for (i=1; i<=20; i++) {
       int j;
       unsigned long long fac = 1;

       for ( j = 1; j<=i; ++j) {
          fac *= j;
       }

       printf ("%2i! = %ld\n", i, fac);
    }

return 0;
}
```

From 14! to 20! outputs wrong values.

It either gives a negative number or the number is not big enough.. what is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
printf ("%2i! = %ld\n", i, fac);
```

The problem is here, use proper notation for unsigned long long type value

Try:

```
printf ("%2i! = %llu\n", i, fac);
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `fac` is of type `unsigned long long`. The correct format specifier for this type is is `%llu`:

```
printf ("%2i! = %llu\n", i, fac);
```

Comment: Your fix is correct, the explanation isn't. The problem isn't signed/unsigned, but ll for long long.

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating correctly but printing incorrectly! use %llu :

```
  printf ("%2i! = %llu\n", i, fac);

  20! = 2432902008176640000
```

There!